# Pythonic Way to compare two unordered lists by attributes

Tags: python, list

what is the most pythonic way to compare two unordered lists by one or more of their attributes? 
I would love to know if there is a pythonic way to find out if for each item in a list A there exists an item in list B where the item from list A and the item in list B match in a specified attribute.

In my example case, I have two .zip files in a unit test, and want to test, if the files match, but I am really looking for a good general solution for my personal toolset. 
This was my first attempt:

```
with ZipFile('A.zip') as old:
with ZipFile('B.zip') as new:
oldFileInfo = old.infolist()

allFound = True
for info in new.infolist():
   matches = [item for item in oldFileInfo if item.CRC == info.CRC and \   
              basename(item.filename) == basename(info.filename) ]
   if len(matches) == 0:
       allFound = False
       break
```

Maybe it is trivial, but I have not yet found a nice way how to do it.

Greetings Michael

Comment: Something is wrong with the indentation.

Comment: I agree with both fedorSmirnov and bereal in their answers. One takes how much do you care with performance and the other with readability. What is more important for you? If this part of code is used too much, I would take the first option.

Comment: @ArthurJulião I don't think that sorting and list comparison will be faster. Both solutions are O(n * log n), but `issubset` is something implemented internally in C, while custom iteration will be in Python. Might be worth checking though.

Comment: True, i hadn't saw that @bereal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy, you should use sets:

```
if set(list1).difference(set(list2)):
    # lists are different
    # different_items = set(list1).difference(set(list2))
    pass
else:
    # lists are the same
    pass
```

You can convert your structure to iterables or lists:

```
list1 = [(i.CRC, basename(i.filename)) for i in old.infolist()]
list2 = [(i.CRC, basename(i.filename)) for i in new.infolist()]
```

Comment: thank you. This was very clear and simple. - But the others weren't bad either.

Comment: This is kind of wrong because [1,2,3,3,3,3] should not be equal to [2,3,1]

Comment: @polvoazul I dont think so - please read the question. All items from list A [1,2,3,3,3,3] are presented in list B [2,3,1]. And yes, all items from list B are presenteed in list A too. So these lists are equal in this case. If you want to compare list one by one, just use len(A) == len(B) as the additional topmost condition.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do it can be:

```
def areEqual(old, new):
    set1 = set((x.attribute1, x.attribute2) for x in old)
    set2 = set((x.attribute1, x.attribute2) for x in new)

    return set1 == set2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create sets out of old and new lists and then compare them:

```
old_set = set((item.CRC, item.filename) for item in old_info)
new_set = set((item.CRC, item.filename) for item in new_info)

all_match = new_set.issubset(old_set)  # or old_set.issuperset(new_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by sorting the lists. It has only a bigO of n log n and then you can just compare the elements one by one and stop if you find a pair that does not match.